# How to calculate driving distance between two latitude and longitudes in PHP

Tags: mysql, google-maps

I have a database which contains many latitude and longitudes.
I need to get all the latitudes and longitudes sorted in ascending order by distance with respect to a latitude and longitude which I can set manually.
I used a formula to solve this problem which is:

```
SELECT id, ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians(37) ) * cos( radians( lat ) ) * cos( radians( lng ) - radians(-122) ) + sin( radians(37) ) * sin( radians( lat ) ) ) ) AS distance 
FROM markers HAVING distance < 25 ORDER BY distance LIMIT 0 , 20;
```

37 and -122 are the latitudes and longitudes and it will return all the values in a field named distance in a sorted way.
My problem is that's not my necessity if a spot is 2 km away but driving distance is 11 km. I need a formula based on google maps which will calculate and return the driving distance between two coordinates.

Comment: If only GIS was this easy.

Answer (score 2):

You can calculate the straight line distance, you can't "calculate" the driving distance without a routing database/engine.

If you need the driving distance, you can use either the [Google directions API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/) (for a single route, potentially with waypoints) or the [Google distance matrix API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/distance-matrix/) (can provide results for multiple origin/destinations)